# Gimp - fix distortion of old photos

Tags: gimp, photo-editing

I got some old photos to my hand. Unfortunately, I didn't have a possibility to make a direct scan of them and I could make a quick photo of them with my mobile phone.

Their quality is acceptable, but the image is distorted (= photo in the image is not rectangular). Is there any way to fix the distortion with Gimp?

I know there is a Perspective-tool but it does not do what I need. I would expect that I make a (non-rectangular) selection of image area and click "This should be rectangle".

[image: Example of image - as you can see the photo in the image is not rectangular]

Comment: ok, image added to the question

Comment: You can avoid these issues by using a scanner.

Answer (score 1):

You want the Perspective tool, but check the `Direction: "corrective (backwards)"` option. Then drag the 4 handles to the corners of you image, and Gimp will make that a rectangle.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to do only an half of the work. The image is now correctly stretched and cropped. But the sides are still concave and not the straight lines.

Comment: You can try `Filter>Distorts>Curve bend` (after rotating the picture 90°). But IMHO the biggest problem is the reflection of the flash.